# Calculate the size occupied by a filtered table not directly present in system.parts in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I have a table called `Master_table` in Clickhouse, I am bale to calculate the size occupied by this table since it is present in `system.parts`.

However, I need to calculate the size occupied by only certain rows in this table, which I would filter by some unique IDs.

I am able to check the size occupied by the `Mater_table` table using the below query:

```
SELECT
    database,
    table,
    formatReadableSize(sum(data_compressed_bytes) AS size) AS compressed,
    formatReadableSize(sum(data_uncompressed_bytes) AS usize) AS uncompressed   
FROM system.parts
WHERE (active = 1) AND (table = 'Master_table')
GROUP BY
    database,
    table
ORDER BY size DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in ClickHouse is stored in column files, so looking at the space of a subset of rows is not going to be an exact science. However, you could estimate it by assuming that storage of each column is the same. With that assumption, you could just figure out the rows you're interested in is as a percentage of the overall dataset.

I tried it out with a table named `flights` and looked at flights from American Airlines (the `airline` column was equal to "AA"):

```
WITH
    (
        SELECT countIf(airline='AA')/count() FROM flights
    ) AS fraction
SELECT
    database,
    `table`,
    formatReadableSize(sum(data_compressed_bytes) AS size) AS compressed,
    formatReadableSize(sum(data_uncompressed_bytes) AS usize) AS uncompressed,
    fraction,
    formatReadableSize(size * fraction) AS subset_usage
FROM system.parts
WHERE (active = 1) AND (`table` = 'flights')
GROUP BY
    database,
    `table`
ORDER BY size DESC
```

Here's the response:

```
┌─database─┬─table───┬─compressed─┬─uncompressed─┬────────────fraction─┬─subset_usage─┐
│ default  │ flights │ 105.09 MiB │ 173.29 MiB   │ 0.13900430815375672 │ 14.61 MiB    │
└──────────┴─────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Good point. Initially I thought about using `select _part from Master_table with_your_condition` and use these part id, but then realized that one part contains lots of data, not just data matching the filtered condition.